# Django filter many-to-many unexpected result

Tags: django

```
class Meet(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(MeetType)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    limit_per_day = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=30)
    start_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    finish_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)


class MeetList(models.Model):
    meet = models.ForeignKey(Meet)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)


owner = User.objects.create_user(username='owner', email='owner@gmail.com', password='pass2')

meet = Meet.objects.create(name='test_meet', owner=owner, type=meettype, start_at=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 11),finish_at=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 14))
meet2 = Meet.objects.create(name='test_meet2', owner=owner, type=meettype, start_at=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 11),finish_at=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 14))

MeetList.objects.create(meet=meet, user=owner)
MeetList.objects.create(meet=meet2, user=owner)
```

MeetList.objects.all() and get

```
MeetList.objects.all()[0].meet.name
u'test_meet'

MeetList.objects.all()[1].meet.name
u'test_meet2'
```

Then i want to filter by user, but i get next

```
MeetList.objects.filter(user=owner)[0].meet.name
u'test_meet2'

MeetList.objects.filter(user=owner)[1].meet.name
u'test_meet2'
```

Why is `MeetList.objects.filter(user=owner)[0].meet.name` the same as `MeetList.objects.filter(user=owner)[1].meet.name`?

Comment: did you check for duplicate objects in database ?

Comment: SELECT "meet_meetlist"."id", "meet_meetlist"."meet_id", "meet_meetlist"."user_id" FROM "meet_meetlist" WHERE "meet_meetlist"."user_id" = 2;

return 2 rows id, meet_id, user_id
8,7,2
9,8,2

Comment: so i want to get `meet` of concrete user.

Comment: define a `__unicode__()` method (`__str__()` method in python 3) on the `Meet` class that prints out its name and print the `MeetList.objects.all()` and `MeetList.objects.filter(user=owner)`.

Comment: i have made `list(MeetList.objects.filter(user=owner))` and get expected result.